# Spring R2DBC Repos auto configuration not resolving dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I Have the following repository: https://github.com/vlio20/bfit in which I try to use R2DBC in order to do db operations in an async manner.
I followed the following tutorial (but maybe it is outdated https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvO4zLVDkMs

Here are the relevant dependancies of my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.jasync-sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasync-r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using the default configurations, so I only have the following configuration in my properties yaml:

```
server:
  port: 2121

spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${env:default}

  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bf_db
    username: root
    password: root

app:
  name: Bfit
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file
> [/Users/vioffe/personal/bfit/api/target/classes/com/bfit/api/user/controller/UserController.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file
> [/Users/vioffe/personal/bfit/api/target/classes/com/bfit/api/user/service/UserService.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in
> com.bfit.api.user.db.UserRepo defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories
> declared on
> R2dbcRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableR2dbcRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'r2dbcEntityTemplate' while setting
> bean property 'entityOperations'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'r2dbcEntityTemplate' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/r2dbc/R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'r2dbcEntityTemplate'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'r2dbcConverter' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/r2dbc/R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'r2dbcConverter'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'r2dbcMappingContext' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/r2dbc/R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'r2dbcMappingContext'
> parameter 1; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'r2dbcCustomConversions' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/r2dbc/R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.R2dbcCustomConversions]:
> Factory method 'r2dbcCustomConversions' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/data/convert/JodaTimeConverters

Here is the full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/X4DGm4rQ

Comment: Please add stacktraces as Text not as image

Comment: @Jens, you can see the link to the stack trace in the question. It is a text there, not an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/convert/JodaTimeConverters
```

mentioned, you miss the `spring-data-commons` jar. Add it as dependency and the error should be solved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: added the dependency as you suggested but it didn't help. I have added a commit with the addition you suggested. Here is the exception: https://pastebin.com/n89XBsHP

Comment: Have you rebuild and redeployed your application?

Comment: I am on intellij, so I have reimported the maven dependencies and relaunched the application

Comment: When I added the right version it worked. Thanks @jens